# Calculating two-tailed p-value from z-score for ROC AUC comparison

Tags: p-value, roc, auc

I am comparing two predictive models by their bootstrapped ROC AUCs with the method originally described by [Hanley and McNeil](http://pubs.rsna.org/doi/abs/10.1148/radiology.148.3.6878708) and modified for bootstrapped data by [Robin et al.](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/12/77)

I'm calculating the z-score as $Z = \textrm{mean}(\frac{D}{\textrm{sd}(D)})$, where $D$ is a group of AUC differences between two models for a number of bootstrap replicates. Then I find out the p-value as $p = 1 - \textrm{cdf}(\textrm{abs}(Z))$, where $\textrm{cdf}$ is the cumulative normal distribution function.

Now, I'm confused about one- and two-tailed p-values. If my aim is to test whether there is significant difference (to any direction) between these AUC distributions, is this method OK? If not, what should I do? Multiply the resulting p-value by two? I've read about the issue, but cannot quite get my mind around the practical implications.